# Is it an acceptable practice to raise exceptions within another exception handler in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql, oracle12c

Currently in a stored procedure I am using an anonymous PL/SQL block around a select into to validate some business rules. If there is an issue with finding said data, I want to handle the **no_data_found** exception and raise a custom exception denoting a security violation. Currently I am doing as follows:

```
    -- verify company has access to equipment
    begin
        select n.fk_org_id
            into v_tmp_org_id
        from transtic.notification n
        where n.fk_ta_id = p_ta_id
            and n.fk_notification_type_id=1
            and n.fk_org_id = v_org_id;
    exception
        when no_data_found then
            v_ret(1):='Error';
            v_ret.extend;
            v_ret(v_ret.last):= 'Action not allowed, User company does not have access to specified equipment.';
            raise edart_error.e_SecurityDataViolation;
    end;
```

Is this method an acceptable practice or should I check for null on **v_tmp_org_id** and raise the exception outside this anonymous block after the fact?

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to substitute a bespoke exception which means something to your application for a generic Oracle one.

Comment: @APC thanks for the reply, i'm just making sure raising the exception within the anonymous made sense in practice or if it would be more readable/standard to others if I only did the error handling for no_data_found then check after to raise the custom defined one.

Comment: If there is no data found, there will be a no_data_found exception in this level. So you can raise an edart_error.e_SecurityDataViolation exception here and maybe deal with it in the main block.

Comment: @ErgiNushi this exactly what im going for in the code above! I just was unsure if this practice made sense, since I never saw anything about raising exceptions within exception handlers in the oracle documentation.